# Date conversion in SQL from 10-09-2020 to 2020-09-10

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, where-clause

I want to convert it for comparing data & here I am stuck.

I have data in date column like `10-09-2020`

```
where convert(varchar, date, 111) >= '2020-09-10'
  AND convert(varchar, date, 111) <= '2020-09-10'
```

I tried 43 also at the place of 111

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (That code will not work on both.)

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: Why convert your date to a string - just for comparison?? Makes no sense - just compare `where date >= '20200910' and date <= '20200930'` or whatever you need . I'd recommend to use the language-neutral `YYYYMMDD` format - always.

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: what you wan to achieve ? convert function expects 2 parameter you pass 3 ? why varchar and why 111 ?

Comment: `convert(...,111)` generates 'yyyy/mm/dd'. I would use `convert(...,112)` -> 'yyyymmdd'. Or even `where [date] between '20200910' and '20200910'`

Comment: The date is stored as varchar in Indian Format in database which I cannot change from my end and date I am taking from Input type. Let me try to convert both to this ( 20200910 ) format

Comment: "The date is stored as varchar" There's your problem right there.

Comment: @AwaisUsmani no, `CONVERT` expects 2 or 3 parameters. [CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The data type to convert to, the value to convert and (optionally) a style code. It's been like that since it was introduced in T-SQL. That *includes* in SyBase way back in 1992: [CONVERT function [Data type conversion\]](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm)

Comment: If you *are* storing a date as a `varchar` then converting it to a `varchar` is going to achieve nothing; converting a value to the data type it already is won't change it. But, like @ZoharPeled implies, if that is the case, you need to fix your design and change the data type of the column.

Comment: That issue I have no authority to change data type from my end and it was already there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a date, don't convert it to a string: compare it as a date instead:

```
where date >= '20200910'
```

`YYYYMMDD` is the safest string format in SQL Server to represent a date.

---

**Edit**

If your are storing your dates as *strings* in format `DD-MM-YYYY`, then you can turn them to dates first, the compare:

```
where datefromparts(right(date_string, 4), substring(date_string, 4, 2), left(date_string, 2)) >= '20200910'
```

You should consider changing your data model to use the proper datatype. Storing dates as strings is inefficient and unsafe for the integrity of your data. See the answer by Larnu on how to proceed to convert the datatype of your column.

Comment: Date is stored as 10-09-2020  this format as varchar. So I need to convert. From client side I can convert input in your favourable format but how to column data to this format

Answer (score 1):

The *real* problem here, which is revealed in the comments under the question, is this:

> The date is stored as varchar

Storing dates as a `varchar` is ***always*** the wrong thing the do. You need to fix your design. This can be achieved with the below:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET YourDate = REPLACE(YourDate, '-'. '/');

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET YourDate = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,YourDate, 103),112);
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourDate date;
```

Note you may need to change the style in the second `UPDATE`, as I have ***assumed*** `dd-MM-yyyy` as the format.

If this still fails, then you have bad data in your data (another reason why a `varchar` is the **wrong** choice for your data type). You can find out the bad rows with the following (again using an appropriate style code):

```sql
SELECT YourDate
FROM dbo.YourTAble
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,YourDate, 103) IS NULL;
```

You're need to fix those values, and then you can run the above.

Finally, you'll then be able to use the solution from GMB to get the results you want.

Comment: Hi friend I know this is a problem but I can not change it from my side. I know how to change but It's not possible

Comment: Why is it not possible, @ROHITNEHRA ? Fixing the design is the only correct solution here. Your database, otherwise, in inherently flawed. According to *your* database, for example, the "date" `'10/09/2020'` is **before** `'11/01/2009'`; where as in actually the first value is over 11 years *after* (or perhaps a little under, as is that 10 September or October 09, we don't know). Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: I am only allowed to use SELECT statement here. I also propose this solution but not allowed to do as date is in Indian understandable format here isn't allowed to interfare.

Comment: A `date` datatype is far more understandable than a string that represents one, @ROHITNEHRA. I can assure you that in no country is `'10/09/2020'` *before* `'11/01/2009'`. If would made no sense to have a query with `WHERE YourDate >= '10/09/2020'` and you get data for years prior.

Comment: I know it make no sense we can understand but corporate needs solution without giving there input. Here is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is stored using a native type, then no conversion is necessary.  If it is not already a `date`, then convert it:

```
where convert(date, datecol) = '2020-09-10'
```

There is one internationalization setting that interprets this as YYYY-DD-MM.  Although I am fine with the hyphens, it is better as:

```
where convert(date, datecol) = '20200910'
```

If the value is stored as a string, it is unclear whether `'10-09-2020'` is DD-MM-YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY.  So, you should use one of:

```
try_convert(date, datecol, 110)   -- for mm-dd-yyyy
try_convert(date, datecol, 105)   -- for dd-mm-yyyy
```

Note that this uses `try_convert()`.  If dates are stored as strings, you cannot be sure that the values are correct.  You might want to see if there are any invalid values.